# Browse files with specific extention in web browser?

Tags: html, browser, file-upload

In our web based application we allow users to upload files.

I wonder if after clicking browse button we can **restrict the list of available files** to be uploaded by **file extension**. `*.zip` for example. Just to give the user easier way to find, select and click the file name.

I guess there will be javascript base solution but can I do it without javascript?

NOTE: this questions is only about making the **browse dialogue to display less files**.

Comment: Is **restriction** what you want or do you just want to make the dialogue more convenient?

Comment: I want to make the browse dialogue more convenient for users to find and select the file they are going to upload. Let's assume they have looots of files on their desktop or download folder.

Comment: Sadly, that can't be done using HTML and JavaScript alone. I wonder why. It would be very useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, `<input type="file" accept="application/zip">` should work. Sadly, no mayor browser supports it...

You can use JavaScript to allow zip files only, but they will still appear in the list.

**Edit:**

For restriction purposes, you could use JavaScript, but you'd still have to perform server-side verification (with PHP, for example).

For a more convenient dialogue, you could use a Flash or Java Applet solution.

Links:

[Flash Uploader](http://www.solmetra.com/en/disp.php/en_products/flash_uploader)

[JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net)

Both allow you to limit the file extensions (among many other customizations).

Comment: What about javascript solution?

Comment: You can only use JavaScript to validate the file extension **after the file has been selected**. There's no way to eliminate non-zip files from the list...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set a file extension filter for the file browse dialogue. The best you can do client-side is to pass the file name through a javascript function on submit, and parse the extension to see if it is legal before proceeding with the upload.

Always bare in mind that your users will still be able to upload any files they choose, no-matter what you try to do client-side. You should always have a server-side check to ensure people aren't uploading malicious scripts.